# incrementing a counter array for 1000 random integers and passing the array to the main method

Tags: java, arrays

I have been at this all day and am a little frustrated at this point.  I have watched several videos on arrays, read my text etc.  However, I am confused on a couple of issues with my program.  I am developing a program that will generate 1000 random integers, store those integers in an array and calculate the frequency of the random integers generated. No errors are showing in my IDE, but, when it is compiled i get an out of bounds error.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at randomintegers.RandomIntegers.calcFrequency(RandomIntegers.java:32)
at randomintegers.RandomIntegers.main(RandomIntegers.java:23)
```

Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Here is my code so far:

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {

    int randomNumbers[] = new int [1000];
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<1000;i++){
    randomNumbers[i] = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    calcFrequency(randomNumbers);
    }
}


public static void calcFrequency(int[] inputArray){
    int freq[]=new int[10];
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<inputArray.length;i++){
        ++freq[inputArray[i]-1];    
    }
    System.out.println("number/tfrequncy");
    System.out.println(freq);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `calcFrequency` from inside the for loop that is filling up the array:

```
for (i=0;i<1000;i++){
    randomNumbers[i] = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    // The first iteration of this loop has only put one value in random numbers
    // So the following will be a mostly empty array:
    calcFrequency(randomNumbers);
}
```

Empty arrays of int's are all set to zero, so when the time comes for freq[inputArray[i]-1], an i of 1 will result in freq[0-1] or the -1 index error you're seeing.

Instead, you'll want to calcFrequency once you're array is all done:

```
for (i=0;i<1000;i++){
    randomNumbers[i] = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 10);
}
calcFrequency(randomNumbers);
```

Comment: Duh!! Thx so much.  Unfortunately, now my output looks like this '[I@28ce41cc' where the frequency is supposed to be listed.

Comment: You're dumping the actual array ( System.out.println(freq) ), so Java will treat your numbers as if they were characters (ASCII table - e.g. the number 91 is character '[', your first frequency value). You'd be better off looping through your freq array and do e.g. System.out.println(freq[i].toString()); or System.out.println(freq[i]+"");

Answer (score 0):

First, why do you put your calcFrequency inside the for loop.
It will be reached before the program put enough random number into it.

Because the array has not been filled,
calcFrequency function cannot find the object you want which generate error

Comment: Another point to address out, when you call the constructor int randomNumbers[] = new int [1000]; it only put null value in each spot.

Comment: Not with int's - their special as they are value types. Zero's are put in each spot rather than nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a couple things:

1) When you iterate over an array, use the array's length as the condition:

```
for( int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i )
```

rather than

```
for( int i = 0; i < someArbitraryNumberThatYoullHaveToUpdateLaterIfYouChangeTheArray; ++i )
```

2) You're generating random numbers <del>[1, 10]</del> [0, 9] and adding 1 to them to get a range of [1, 10], then using them in `calcFrequency` to index the array, which has elements [0, 9]. Which will overrun the high end of the array. You tried to address this by subtracting 1, but what happens when you get 0?

3) Rather than trying adjust your numbers in the array, simply augment them when printing them out.

```
System.out.println( (randoms[i] + 1) + " occured " + counts[i] + " times" );
```

Comment: ok i took your suggestion for array.length. That makes sense, but, my math.random function should only generate 1-10 as that is the scope of the program, hence, a value for zero should not need to be addressed.  Even so, after fixing this is my output [I@6e8d1800 with no errors in my editor.

Comment: Well, `System.out.println( someArray );` will output the memory location of the array. Use `Arrays.toString(someArray)` - you'll need to import Arrays. If you add 1 now or later, did the value ever really change? (No) But your way is much harder to work with (as you now know)

Comment: Ahhh! Thx so much.  I couldn't get it to work at first b/c i have never used java.util.arrays but i figured it out.  Hopefully, my prof doesn't penalize me for finding out this import exists!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0;i<1000;i++){
  randomNumbers[i] = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 10);
  calcFrequency(randomNumbers);
}
```

Change the code above to:

```
for (i=0;i<1000;i++){
  randomNumbers[i] = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 10);
}
calcFrequency(randomNumbers);
```

You should first initialize every element of the array and then calculate the frequencies. Otherwise, all uninitialized elements have a default value `0`.

The following line was the cause of the exception:

```
++freq[inputArray[i]-1];
```

When the current element has the default value `0`, this line becomes:

```
++freq[-1];
```

which gives you `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`.

By the way, if you want to print the array, the following won't work:

```
System.out.println(freq);
```

Instead, you might want to do:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(freq));
```